# Working with Registry in C# 2.0 (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, .net-2.0

I'm a newbie to Windows Forms.

I'm designing an Windows Application in .Net Framework 2.0 in which, 
I need to Store a UserName and Password somewhere in the System and access them every time I open My Application and Some times I need to change those credentials on User command.

I heard registry is the Best way in doing so. I know Nothing About Using Registry in C# .Net.

So Can you Help me in

How To Get Values which are In Registry, and how to Set a Value to Registry. ??

I'm Using .Net Framework 2.0

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subject is very broad. You should start reading on MSDN about the class

[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx)

**But I really suggest to avoid the registry altogether.**
Allowing the registry to store configuration info for normal applications  has been a mistake from the start by Microsoft.

You could write a simple hashing function, apply it to your username and password and store the result in a file located in the ApplicationData folder. 
At the next run check if the file exist, read it and compare its content with the hashing of username and password.

Here a rough example, just to let you start on your own code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = "Steve";
    string pass = "MyPass";

    string hashedUser = GetHashedText(user);
    string hashedPass = GetHashedText(pass);

    string file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath 
                       (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
                       "MyKeys.txt");

    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string recordedUser = sr.ReadLine();
            string recordedPass = sr.ReadLine();
            if (recordedUser == user && recordedPass == pass)
                MessageBox.Show("User validated");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid user");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(hashedUser);
            sw.WriteLine(hashedPass);
        }

    }
}

private string GetHashedText(string inputData)
{ 
    byte[] tmpSource;
    byte[] tmpData;
    tmpSource = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputData);
    tmpData = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(tmpSource);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(tmpData);
}
```

EDIT: Based on your comment, it seems that you need a crypt and decrypt function. The code below is taken and adapted from the [Extension Overflow](http://extensionoverflow.codeplex.com/), where you can find other useful methods.
Now, before write to disk, call the Encrypt method with the string to encrypt and a key. After reading, call the Decrypt method passing the crypted text and the secret key.

```
string cryptedUser = Encrypt(user, "your_secret_key_ABCDEFG");
....

public string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string key)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToEncrypt))
        throw new ArgumentException("An empty string value cannot be encrypted.");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt using an empty key.");

    CspParameters cspp = new CspParameters();
    cspp.KeyContainerName = key;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp);
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
    byte[] bytes = rsa.Encrypt(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt), true);
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}

string clearText = Decrypt(cryptedText, "your_secret_key_ABCDEFG");
....

public string Decrypt(string stringToDecrypt, string key)
{
    string result = null;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToDecrypt))
        throw new ArgumentException("An empty string value cannot be encrypted.");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot decrypt using an empty key");
    try
    {
        CspParameters cspp = new CspParameters();
        cspp.KeyContainerName = key;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp);
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
        string[] decryptArray = stringToDecrypt.Split(new string[] { "-" }, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.None);
        byte[] decryptByteArray = Array.ConvertAll<string, byte>
                                 (decryptArray, (s => Convert.ToByte(byte.Parse(s,
                                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
        byte[] bytes = rsa.Decrypt(decryptByteArray, true);
        result = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
    finally
    {
        // no need for further processing
    }
    return result;
}
```

Of course, I assume that the security level required by your application allows that username ans passwords will be stored in the local system. (And as you know, everything that is stored on the local system is not very secure)

Comment: how would It be to Hash the Credentials and store into Registry??

Comment: You told how to Encrypt using Hashing. Thanks for that, But How to Decrypt the Hashed text and take the String from it??

Comment: @KrishnaThota: I think the sample is assuming you will be doing the user validation yourself. If you need the credentials to connect to another service (building a connection string for example) hashing isn't the right solution.

Comment: The purpose of a function that computes a hash is to generate a string that can not be 'normally' decrypted (one-way hash function). You compare the hash value obtained by your inputs with the hash value you have stored. In the example I have used the MD5CryptoServiceProvider, but if you search in the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx) namespace you will find other CryptoServiceProvider with strong (but slower) encryption scheme like SHA1, SHA256 etc.

Comment: Here I need to Store User Credentials some where and then on every Application Start I have to Use them to Connect to a Website. So I need to Decrypt the Hashed String. If I can not Decrypt the Hashed Variables what should I use?

Comment: Well, now this comment is a whole game changer. I will try to update my answer to include a crypt/decrypt function that your can use as replacement for GetHashedText

Answer (score 2):

Check this tutorial with read, write and delete function for registry

[Read, write and delete from registry with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial that will explain read/write to registry.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-editing-the-windows-registry

There are few more things you need to know about registry.

1. Registry consists of five sections of which HKEY_CURRENT_USER stores the settings of currently logged in user. It is recommended that you store the settings under this key. Settings are stored generally in HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software//
2. You can store machine wide settings (applicable to all users using the computer) under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key. However, read/write operations to this requires administrative rights. Your application must be running in administrator privilege to write to this key.
3. Make sure that your registry reading mechanism returns default values if it is not found in the registry as well as write the default values to registry. This way, you will never run out of setting values.
4. Registry can be edited and can be read. If you are planning to store username/password combination in registry, make sure you encrypt it before you store it. Further, to make sure that it is not used on any other computer also, you should encrypt it with some machine specific information.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using IsolatedStorage. [MSDN Blurb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [code sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6535/Isolated-Storage-in-NET-to-store-application-data), and (given you're storing user credentials) an [encryption sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6465/Using-CryptoStream-in-C). I've linked .net 2.0 samples where possible.

Storing application data in the registry has become unpopular since there are easier alternatives and using the registry can hurt the performance of your users' computers.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the registry but first thing that comes up on google is [this](http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/using-the-registry-SID216.aspx). Seems like fairly easy to understand so have fun with it :)

Answer (score 1):

doing it the registry way is the wrong way to go, , i believe do a config file and read this config is much better way to go. but anyway here how you do registry thing

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

Comment: for saving application preferences not application data, I didn't say that you cant, I said its wrong to do it, and it makes your application pretty dependent, and you need to have a permission to access this key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask yourself a couple of questions:

1. Should only one user be able to use the uid/password?
2. How safe should the password be stored?

It's quite easy to store information in the registry.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

If you just want to store it for one user, store it under HKEY_CURRENT_USER/software/your_company/your_product otherwize store it under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/software/your_company/your_product.

If your password is to be stored safely, there are safer solutions than the registry.

Comment: Can you tell me a safer solution ??

Comment: It depends on your  setup. Are you doing a Windows-exe client program? What will you connect to? E.g A db server? A webservice? A com component?

Comment: I'm using the User Credentials of a website used to Send SMS to mobiles. I'm creating a windows application (.exe)