# How to encrypt and save a password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on the security issue in .net application and I have been reported that My code is vulnerable and I see the issue is the way I store the password

For example:

```
<add key="RegxxxChannelPassword" value="test"/>
<add key="xxxRegistrationConnStr" value="xxxxxxxxxx;
```

So my tool was showing that storing the password in plain text is dangerous .

So can I encrpt the password and save it?

Can some one please suggest me if there are any algorithms?

Comment: Yes, password encryption has been around for quite some time. Have you bothered to research the problem yourself at all?

Comment: There are tons of examples on how to encrypt and decrypt plain text. [Look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450201/working-with-registry-in-c-sharp-2-0-windows-forms/13450315#13450315) for example and the second part of my answer

Comment: What tool is saying this? It is a fairly standard place to store database credentials. You could make a custom utility for decrypting the web.config connection string password. It would involve storing a decryption key at some other location for use internally within the application. I can't see this being necessary though.

Comment: `It would involve storing a decryption key at some other location for use internally within the application` The problem is exactly this. where? how?

Answer (score 2):

It'd be much more simple to use a membership provider. If you're doing the encryption on your own you're reinventing the wheel and disregarding what the framework could do for you.

I suggest you [go read about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx).

The relevant property of the provider, in this case, is `passwordFormat`.

**Edit:** for a moment there I thought you were talking about user passwords. If it's a password for a connection string, it should be in a .config file, like web.config. If you have it in the proper place, VS won't complain about it being unencrypted, since it's content that will never get served to a client anyway.

Comment: you are right . I was talking about the web.config but I am using the same connection strings in many places of my app.So  I was wandering how that can be encrypted and I think Once I encrypt the password in web.config file .I can use the same at all places.

Comment: You don't have to encrypt it. Just use it the way it's intended, and you'll get no warnings or errors. I suggest you look at some code examples containing connection strings in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt sections of the web.config using aspnet_regiis, but the web.config is a pretty standard place to store passwords and such, as long as the website is deployed to a server that you own. You could also put the values in the registry, but in most cases, that's unnecessary. Here's an article on encrypting web.config sections:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

If you go that route, you'll run the command to encrypt the web.config as a deployment step, and the application will handle decrypting and using the values on its own.

Comment: True and this certainly gives some people piece of mind.  However, the simple fact that because the web application itself has the rights to decrypt this then once an attacker has access to the root site to pull the web.config they almost always have rights to inject code anyway.. which makes it trivial to pull a decrypted string from the web.config.   tldr; it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you have a look that Rijndael for two-way encryption, if you want to store your password in Web.config:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx

I agree with @Renan, the proper way to go, is to use MembershipProvider.