# String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I am working on Decrypt Password and I stuck on this error:

> String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue

Kindly help on this error or suggest me another program for decryption.

Here is the full code:

```
string decryptpwd = string.Empty;
UTF8Encoding encodepwd = new UTF8Encoding();
Decoder Decode = encodepwd.GetDecoder();
byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptpwd.Replace("+",""));
int charcount = Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
char[] decode_char = new char[charcount];
Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decode_char, 0);
decryptpwd = new String(decode_char);
return decryptpwd;
```

Comment: **Base64 is not encryption**.  You must **hash** passwords.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FreeLancer here is my complete code i use this code from a website

        string decryptpwd = string.Empty;
        UTF8Encoding encodepwd = new UTF8Encoding();
        Decoder Decode = encodepwd.GetDecoder();
        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptpwd.Replace("+",""));
        int charcount = Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decode_char = new char[charcount];
        Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length,    decode_char, 0);
        decryptpwd = new String(decode_char);
        return decryptpwd;

Answer (score 11):

You are asking the Replace method to change an empty string (first parameter) with a plus character (second parameter). This make no sense and Replace is complaining about this.
I think you want to do the reverse

```
 byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptpwd.Replace("+",""));
```

A part from this I am not sure what the result will be when you change something into the input string and apply a FromBase64String to the result. Well, it really depends on what was originally in the string, but for sure (if `encryptpwd` is really a Base64 string) there are no spaces to replace.

Keep in mind that you can't pass a normal string to Convert.FromBase64String, you need a string that is a base 64 string

[What is a base 64 string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

For example

```
string pwd = "786";   // The original string

UnicodeEncoding u = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] x = u.GetBytes(pwd);  // The Unicode bytes of the string above

// Convert bytes to a base64 string
string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(x);
Console.WriteLine(b64);

// Go back to the plain text string    
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
string result = u.GetString(b);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

A final word. Someone (@Slacks) already tells you that a base64 string is not an encryption technology and you shouldn't use it for *crypting* passwords (They are not crypted at all)

Comment: i try this it give the error
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Comment: Actually when i enter the password 786 it gives error  Invalid length for a Base-64 char array after it i add ("+","") then it give the error "String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue"

Comment: Where do you get the string 786? You cannot take an arbitrary string and pass it to FromBse64String. You need a Base64String. Something that you get out from Convert.ToBase64String(). I will add an example

Comment: I design and develop a login form where i want decrypt and encrypt function so i use this .786 is a password which was enter by a user .

Comment: I can only suggest to search on the subject Crypting and store passwords. The argument is very broad. [Look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450201/working-with-registry-in-c-sharp-2-0-windows-forms/13450315#13450315) where in the second part of my answer I explain how to crypt and decrypt a plain text

Comment: Thanks Steve so kind of you

Answer (score 7):

```
encryptpwd.Replace("","+")
```

What exactly are you replacing? You haven't specified an original value to be replaced.

`String.Replace` takes two string arguments `oldValue` and `newValue`.  You specified the newValue `+` however an empty string is not legal for the `oldValue`.

Therefore if you want to replace a blank space with `+` try:

```
encryptpwd.Replace(" ","+");
```

Or vice versa:

```
encryptpwd.Replace("+"," ");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

Comment: i also try your solution i get that error

Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Answer (score 2):

problem is here

```
encryptpwd.Replace("","+")
```

Should have some character or string to replace

```
encryptpwd.Replace(" ","+")
```

Comment: @Rajev i try your solution after it i get that error 
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Answer (score -3):

Error **String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue**

**If You want to separate the individual characters from a string.**

try this:-

```
   int l=0;
   string str = Console.ReadLine();
   while(l <= str.Length -1)
   {
       Console.Write("{0} ", str[l]);
       l++;
   }
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?